# $\lambda \ll \mu$, $\mu X <\infty$, then $\lambda X<\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

$\lambda \ll\mu$ : $\lambda$ is absolutely continuous w.r.t. $\mu$.

and $\mu X \lt\infty$, where $X$ is a space

how to show: $\lambda X\lt\infty$

Comment: Please state exactly how "absolutely continuous"  is defined for you.  The way I usually understand it, it means that if $\mu(A)=0$ then $\lambda(A)=0$, and in that case your claim is false.

Comment: yes it as you stated. how is it false. could you give an example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is false.  Let $\mu$ be Gaussian measure on $\mathbb{R}$ and $\lambda$ Lebesgue measure.